# Akka Streams: Concatenating streams that initialise resources

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have two streams: **A** and **B**.

- **A** is writing a file to disk and appends its elements during its execution.
- **B** is reading that file and does some processing with the data.

Only AFTER **A** is done with processing and writing its data to the file, I want to start with **B**.

I tried to `concat` the two streams with:

```
A.concat(
  Source.lazily { () =>
    println("B is getting initialised")
    getStreamForB()
  }
)
```

But this is already initialising **B** BEFORE **A** has finished.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [ticket](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/23044) tracking the fact that `Source#concat` does not support lazy materialization. That ticket mentions the following work-around:

```
implicit class SourceLazyOps[E, M](val src: Source[E, M]) {
  def concatLazy[M1](src2: => Source[E, M1]): Source[E, NotUsed] =
    Source(List(() => src, () => src2)).flatMapConcat(_())
}
```

Applying the above implicit class to your case:

```
A.concatLazy(
  Source.lazily { () =>
    println("B is getting initialised")
    getStreamForB()
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`FileIO.toPath`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/FileIO$.html) method will materialize the stream into a `Future[IOResult]`.  If you are working with stream `A` that is writing to a file:

```
val someDataSource : Source[ByteString, _] = ???

val filePath : Path = ???

val fileWriteOptions : Set[OpenOption] = ???

val A : Future[IOResult] = 
  someDataSource
    .to(FileIO.toPath(filePath, fileWriteOptions))
    .run()
```

You can use the materialized Future to kick off your stream `B` once the writing is completed:

```
val fileReadOptions : Set[OpenOption] = ???

val someProcessingWithTheDataOfB : Sink[ByteString, _] = ???

A foreach { _ =>

  val B : Future[IOResult] = 
    FileIO
      .fromPath(filePath, fileReadOptions)
      .to(someProcessingWithTheDataOfB)
      .run()
}
```

Similarly, you could do some testing of the `IOResult` before doing the reading to make sure there were no failures during the writing process:

```
A.filter(ioResult => ioResult.status.isSuccess)
 .foreach { _ =>
   val B : Future[IOResult] = 
     FileIO
       .fromPath(filePath, readOptions)
       .to(someProcessingOfB)
       .run()
 }
```